# JavaScript: .replace не работает

Tags: javascript

Если не вдаваться в детали, зачем мне это, то задача следующая: вне зависимости от того, на локольном или удалённом сервере находится сайт, сохранить в значение переменной имя текущего файла без разрешения.

Вот такой код:

```
var fileName = location.href.split("/").slice(-1);
```

// Значение на этом этапе проверил - выводит, например, "info.php"

```
    if (fileName == "#" ||  fileName == "") {var fileName="index";} // Если страница - начальная
    else{
        //alert(fileName); // позиция 1
        fileName = fileName.replace(/\.php$/i,'');
        alert(fileName); // позиция 2

    }
```

Если мы находимся не на главной странице (index.php), то мы попадаем в `else`. Я убедился, что это работает через alert(fileName); в **позиции 1**. Однако в **позиции 2** - уже не работает, т. е. окна нет вообще. Никаких сообщений об ошибке.

Такой код:

```
fileName="info.php";
fileName=fileName.replace(/\.php$/i,''); // 1 в 1 с предыдущим кодом

alert(fileName);
```

я проверил на jsfiddle; там всё работает.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: действительно очень странно, возоможно какие-то нюансы с жадностью как вариант попробуйте описать целую строку
fileName="info.php";
fileName=fileName.replace(/^(.*?)\.php$/i,'$1');

alert(fileName);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас переменная `fileName` массив а не строка. Надо так:

`fileName = fileName.toString().replace(/\.php$/i,'');`

Comment: Благодарю! На Вашем ответе несколько часов изысканий благополучно завершились и код тут же заработал.